# Add field to Django Forms each 3 POST request

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to setup a website which with a small form which will have only one visible field: an EmailField. I am using [a python package](https://github.com/ImaginaryLandscape/django-nocaptcha-recaptcha) to use Google No CAPTCHA ReCATPCHA and I want the captcha (NoReCaptchaField) appear only after the user had correctly submitted the form 3 times.

In my views.py I will create a form passing the boolean *needs_captcha* which is going to be True onces each 3 successful form POST requests (this is working right).

```
form = JoinForm(needs_captcha)
```

Now in my forms.py I have the following code:

```
class JoinForm(forms.ModelForm):

def __init__(self, needs_captcha, *args, **kwargs):
    super(JoinForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if needs_captcha:
        self.captcha = NoReCaptchaField(gtag_attrs={'data-theme': 'light'})
        print("captcha will be included")
    else:
        print("captcha won't be included")

# this is the only field that is actually filled by the user
email = forms.EmailField(max_length=128, help_text="Introduce la cuenta de gmail que tienes asociada a tu"
                                                   " dispositivo Android",
                         widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': "w-input email_input",
                                                        'placeholder': 'Tu cuenta de Google'}),
                         required=True)
.....

def clean(self):
   .....

def clean_email(self):
   .....

    return email

class Meta:
    model = InterestedUser
    fields = ('email', 'name', 'subject', 'via', 'content',)
```

Because not all the JoinForm objects should have the field I tried to add the field in the **init** just for the object from I am creating for this specific request but it just doesn't work, the captcha won't show up. Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, you can't add new fields after super().**init**(). and fields doesn't exist before the _init. So the work around to always include the optional fields and then remove after init if they are not needed.

```
class JoinForm(forms.ModelForm):
    captcha = NoReCaptchaField(gtag_attrs={'data-theme': 'light'})

    class Meta:
        model = InterestedUser
        fields = ('email', 'name', 'subject', 'via', 'content',)

    def __init__(self, needs_captcha, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if not needs_captcha:
            del self.fields['captcha']
```